# How to extract object reference from property access lambda

Tags: c#, reflection, properties

Here's a follow-up question to [Get name of property as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820660/get-name-of-property-as-a-string).

Given a method Foo (error checking omitted for brevity):

```
// Example usage: Foo(() => SomeClass.SomeProperty)
// Example usage: Foo(() => someObject.SomeProperty)
void Foo(Expression<Func<T>> propertyLambda)
{
    var me = propertyLambda.Body as MemberExpression;
    var pi = me.Member as PropertyInfo;
    bool propertyIsStatic = pi.GetGetMethod().IsStatic;
    object owner = propertyIsStatic ? me.Member.DeclaringType : ???;
    ...
    // Execute property access
    object value = pi.GetValue(owner, null);
}
```

I've got the static property case working but don't know how to get a reference to someObject in the instance property case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason that you want to invoke this using reflection rather than compiling the lambda? That appears to be the only reason that you need the owner in the first place...

Comment: The only reason being I'm a lambda newbie :) How would I execute the property access using just the lambda? I just tried this (as a guess):
var v = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(propertyLambda).Compile();
object o = v();
but didn't get an intelligible result.

Comment: Cool...this works:
object o = Expression.Lambda(propertyLambda.Body).Compile().DynamicInvoke();
Thanks for the hint, Adam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MemberExpression` has a property called `Expression`, which is the object on which the member access occurs.

You can get the object by compiling a function which returns it:

```
var getSomeObject = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(me.Expression).Compile();

var someObject = getSomeObject();
```

Comment: That is amazingly cool, and exactly what I needed, in under 4 minutes, even. Sometimes I feel like I'm in a Star Trek episode and all I need to do when I'm stuck is call out, "Computer, what is..." :) Thanks Bryan.

Comment: Haha happy to be of help. I happened to have a solution open in which I have code that extracts property getters from expressions :-)