# Getting property names at compile time

Tags: c#

I have a class with some properties:

```
class Foo
{
    public int Bar { get; set; }
    public string Baz { get; set; }
    public bool Quux { get; set; }
    (...)
}
```

For use in some storage API, I need to specify a subset of these properties, by name as strings:

```
var props = new string[]
{
    "Bar",
    // Don't want this one... "Baz",
    "Quux",
     ...
};
```

This works, but is unsafe - if I mistype "Quux", I won't get a compilation error, just (hopefully) a runetime error. I tried reflection - `typeof(Foo).GetProperties("Bar")` - but that would also fail only in runtime.

Ideally, I'd like to do something like:

```
var props = new string[]
{
    Magic_GetName(Foo.Bar),
    // Don't want this one... Foo.Baz,
    Magic_GetName(Foo.Quux),
     ...
};
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get name of property as a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820660/get-name-of-property-as-a-string)

Comment: @nawfal this is not a duplicate. this question is about "compile time"

Comment: @symbiont both are about static property names, yes compiler should catch at compile time.

Comment: @nawfal no. static and compile time are not the same

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In C# 6.0, you can use the [nameof()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx) keyword:

And then you write:

```
var props = new string[]
{
    nameof(Foo.Bar),
    nameof(Foo.Quux),
     ...
};
```

Everything is done at compile time using this keyword, so it's much better than using lambda expression with code that digs the name of your symbol at runtime. It's better on a performance point of view, and it also works with `switch()` statements:

```
switch(e.PropertyName)
{
    case nameof(Foo.Bar):
        break;
}
```

Using lambda expression or magic get functions, you can't use the `switch()` statement because the `switch()` statement requires to use string literals. Since `nameof()` keywords are converted to string literals at compile time, it works.

Comment: I like this solution

Answer (score 8):

You can use expressions for this. The usage would look like this:

```
Magic_GetName<Foo>(x => x.Bar)
```

The implementation of `Magic_GetName` would look like this:

```
public static string Magic_GetName<TClass>(
    Expression<Func<TClass, object>> propertyExpression)
{
    propertyExpression.Dump();
    var body = propertyExpression.Body as UnaryExpression;
    if (body == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(
            string.Format(
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                "The body of the 'propertyExpression' should be an " +
                "unary expression, but it is a {0}", 
                propertyExpression.Body.GetType()));
    }

    var memberExpression = body.Operand as MemberExpression;
    if (memberExpression == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(
            string.Format(
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                "The operand of the body of 'propertyExpression' should " +
                "be a member expression, but it is a {0}", 
                propertyExpression.Body.GetType()));
    }
    var propertyInfo = memberExpression.Member as PropertyInfo;
    if (propertyInfo == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(
            string.Format(
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                "The member used in the expression should be a property, " +
                "but it is a {0}", 
                memberExpression.Member.GetType()));
    }

    return propertyInfo.Name;
}
```

**Update:**
The title of this question is "Getting property names at **compile** time".
My answer actually doesn't do that. The method `Magic_GetName` is executed at *runtime* and as such has a performance impact.

The .NET 4.5 way using [the `CallerMemberName` attribute](http://danrigby.com/2012/03/01/inotifypropertychanged-the-net-4-5-way/) on the other hand is really [a compile time feature](http://rohiton.net/2012/03/05/caller-information/) and as such doesn't have a runtime impact. However, as I already said in the comments, it is not applicable in the given scenario.

Comment: @Jonathan: The following usages would be possible, too: (1) `Magic_GetName(() => new Foo().Bar)` (2) `Magic_GetName<Foo>(x => x.Bar)`

Comment: @Jonathan: I changed my answer to use the second syntax. I think it's a bit cleaner.

Comment: My friend pointed out that this is a well-known problem in implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`: http://www.bing.com/search?q=property+changed+string+not+hard+coded

Comment: @Jonathan: Indeed, it *was* until .NET 4.5. Now you can just use the [`CallerMemberName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute.aspx) attribute: http://danrigby.com/2012/04/01/inotifypropertychanged-the-net-4-5-way-revisited/ . But that attribute is not applicable in your situation.

Answer (score 4):

Much better way of doing that is

```
GetPropertyName<MemoryDevice>(x => x.DeviceLocator)

public static string GetPropertyName<TClass>(
        Expression<Func<TClass,object>> propertyExpression)
    {
        var body = propertyExpression.ToString();
        body = body.Substring(body.IndexOf(".")+1);
        return body;
    }
```

another way to do that at runtime is

```
public static string GetName<TClass>(
    Expression<Func<TClass, object>> propertyExpression)
{
    var body = propertyExpression.Body as UnaryExpression;
    var memberExpression = body.Operand as MemberExpression;
    var propertyInfo = memberExpression.Member as PropertyInfo;

    return propertyInfo.Name;
}
```