# Get the property name as string in C#

Tags: c#, reflection

Is it possible to write a function that return the string value of a property of an object?

if I have an object called apple that has a method called peel i would like to have a method that returns "peel" when I call getAttributeName(apple.peel).

How can I do it?

Comment: First hit on google: http://www.csharp-examples.net/reflection-property-names/

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: If you know the method is called "peel", you can just put "peel" in a string. Hard to see what's your point here.

Comment: I don't believe you couldn't see one of questions like [Get name of property as a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820660/get-name-of-property-as-a-string) when you typed title of your question

Answer (score 5):

You can write an extension method

```
public static string GetPropName<T, P>(this T obj, Expression<Func<T, P>> lambda)
{
    var member = lambda.Body as MemberExpression;
    var prop = member.Member as PropertyInfo;
    return prop.Name;
}
```

and use it like this

```
var u = new User();
string name = u.GetPropName(x=>x.name);
```