# Implementation of method accepting lambda

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda

I'm interested to understand how are implemented LabelFor, EditorFor... methods that accept lambda expressions in MVC.

Lets say I have a class Person and I want to print the name and the value of a property. How must be implemented Label() and Editor() methods?

```
  class Person
  {
     public int Id { get; set; }
  }

  void Label(Expression<Func<Person, int>> expression)
  {
     //...
  }

  void Editor(Expression<Func<Person, int>> expression)
  {
     //...
  }

  public void Test()
  {
     Person p = new Person
     {
        Id = 42
     };

     Label(x => x.Id );  // print "Id"
     Editor(x => x.Id); // print "42"

  }
```

Comment: First off you need to pass a `Person` to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2820693/382780) to a similar question gives an implementation of `Label`. The code's by Josh Smith in the PropertyObserver class of his MVVM foundation:

```
    private static string GetPropertyName
        (Expression<Func<TPropertySource, object>> expression)
    {
        var lambda = expression as LambdaExpression;
        MemberExpression memberExpression;
        if (lambda.Body is UnaryExpression)
        {
            var unaryExpression = lambda.Body as UnaryExpression;
            memberExpression = unaryExpression.Operand as MemberExpression;
        }
        else
        {
            memberExpression = lambda.Body as MemberExpression;
        }

        Debug.Assert(memberExpression != null, 
           "Please provide a lambda expression like 'n => n.PropertyName'");

        if (memberExpression != null)
        {
            var propertyInfo = memberExpression.Member as PropertyInfo;

            return propertyInfo.Name;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

It works by looking at the expression tree and checking for the name of the property in member expressions.

---

For `Editor`, you can use a similar strategy of looking through the `Expression` to find out what you need about the property. What exactly to do depends a lot on what info you want.

The specific way you asked it where all you want is the value of a property from a `Person`, you can simplify a **lot**. I also added a `Person` parameter, since you seem to want the value for a given person.

```
int Editor(Person person, Func<Person, int> expression)
{
    return expression(person);
}
```

This can be used like `Editor(p, p => p.Id);`. Note that I changed `Expression<Func<Person, int>>` to `Func<Person, int>`, which means that instead of an expression tree it gets a `Func`. You can't examine a `Func` to find names of properties and such, but you can still use it to find the property from the `Person`.

Comment: You should mention that you took a bit of a shortcut with the `Editor` method by taking a `Func<>` instead of an expression tree. In MVC, they need information about the property *in addition to* the value, so they parse the expression tree and use reflection to determine the value.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Good call, edited. Had to be quick, let me know (or propose an edit) if there's something more. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

```
void Label(Expression<Func<Person, int>> expression)
{
    Person myPerson = new Person { Id = 42 };
    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in typeof(Person).GetProperties())
        if(prop.Equals(expression(myPerson))) print(prop.Name);
}

void Editor(Expression<Func<Person, int>> expression)
{
    Person myPerson = new Person { Id = 42 };
    print(expression(myPerson));
}
```

Comment: No, dude. You don't loop through all the properties for the class. And notice how you hard-coded "Person" as the model type.. Are you going to write one of these for every class? No, just no. The lamda expression already has the property's name. See @31eee384 's answer.

Comment: @Daryl He hardcoded `Person` into the `delegate`, so it was safe for me to assume i can re use an existing `Type` according to OP's question. And by the way your treading on ground that is far away from the original question, he doesnt even know the basics of the `delegate` expression. He provided the lambda, and wanted to know how it would be implemented. That is all.

Comment: I think what clarified the question for me was this part of the Q: "I'm interested to understand how are implemented LabelFor, EditorFor... methods that accept lambda expressions in MVC." I think the asker was just simplifying the question by not using generics.

Comment: @Andrew: This code won't work the way you think it will. You can't call `expression(myPerson)` like that, and even if you did, `prop.Equals()` on that would always return false.

Comment: Care to explain why i cant call the expression ´like that´

Comment: Does [this ideone example of the compiler error that results](http://ideone.com/fHuRsS) clarify? It's syntactically invalid--you can compile it to turn it into a delegate though.