# How to display only a property of an item on the ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have added a list of objects of the class "Employee" on a ListView, and i want it to display only the attribute "Name" on it, but when the item is selected, i want it to catch the object "Employee" to add to another List.

Here is my code. It displays the object Employee on the ListView. I want it to display the attribute Name.

```
    private void PopulateEmployeeList()
    {
        List<Employee> staff = Presenter.GetEmployee();
        foreach (Employee person in staff)
            lstEmployee.Items.Add(person);
    }
```

XAML

```
<Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="230" >
            <ListView Name="lstFuncionarios" />
</Border>
```

Comment: take look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820660/get-name-of-property-as-a-string

Comment: Please provide your XAML also.

Comment: The xaml only contains the name of the listview

Comment: I think you're looking for DisplayMemberBinding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try in your xaml:

```
<ListView x:Name="lv" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="149" Margin="359,111,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="138">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define ItemContainerStyle for your ListView:

```
<ListView Name="lstFuncionarios">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}"  >
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

This solution is good if you do not know the final face of ListViewItem, so you will be able to rewrite it when you want.

If you need just to display Name and nothing else - the solution of @S_Lord is good:

```
lstFuncionarios.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
```

or

```
<ListView Name="lstFuncionarios" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
```

Hope, it helps