# Get the column name from list

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to fetch the column names from List. As I have a class

```
public class DetailView

    {
        public string SiteName { get; set; }
        public string ItemType { get; set; }
        public string AssetStorage { get; set; }
    }
```

and in some method in controller am filling the data into Session. Now I want to get the column names for some reason. Am putting my session data into that list.

```
List<DetailView> objgrdDtls = new List<DetailView>();
objgrdDtls = (List<DetailView>)Session["datasetVal"];
```

I would like to have the Column name. Pleas note by doing the below code i got the value of that particular column name. restult1 has the column value.

```
var result1 = objgrdDtls.Where(p => p.SiteName.ToLower().Contains(txt1));
```

But all i need is Column name. So how do i get that.

```
stringColumnname = objgrdDtls.get(columnaname => some filter)?
```

Is this is the way how to get column names?
Not sure how to get the column name one by one? 
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get name of property as a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820660/get-name-of-property-as-a-string)

Comment: I want column name. Didnt get any info in the above link

Answer (score 2):

You can use reflection to get the column name. Here is the runnable example to get the column name of DetailView.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

public class DetailView
{
     public string SiteName { get; set; }
        public string ItemType { get; set; }
        public string AssetStorage { get; set; }


}

    public class Example
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            DetailView fieldsInst = new DetailView();
            // Get the type of DetailView.
            Type fieldsType = typeof(DetailView);

        PropertyInfo[] props = fieldsType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public 
            | BindingFlags.Instance);


        for(int i = 0; i < props.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("   {0}",
                props[i].Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Var result1 will give the list of DetailView Objects which meet the condition "SiteName.ToLower().Contains(txt1)". It will not be a value. Can you please clarify what do you mean by column value. However, For selecting a particular column value, You can append ".Select(p => p.AssetStorage)".

Comment: Column value is the which it has the data in that, i mean say for example, there is a property SiteName for that property there would be data like 'INDIA'. Now i want to get the Column name ie, property name like 'SiteName', ItemType and AssetStorage which i have declared in class Detail View.