# C# Passing / retrieving a property name from a parameter without reflection

Tags: c#, performance, system.reflection

I want to pass a property to a function such that the function knows both the value of the property and the name of the property. This is so I can return errors that match the property names.

I currently have code like this:

```
var userNameField = personField.GetChildField(f => f.UserName, nameof(personField.Value.UserName));
```

many times repeated, so the 2nd parameter is the name of the property inside the lambda of the 1st parameter.

Is it possible to automate this parameter so:

1. The duplicate code is gone
2. The string name of the property is calculated at compile-time, not run-time for every call

Ideally I would like my code to simply look like:

```
var userNameField = personField.GetChildField(f => f.UserName);
```

I have got this working using reflection using `Expression<Func...` i.e. `((MemberExpression) getPropertyFunc.Body).Member.Name;` but this is too slow, in particular compiling the expression into a function which I can use to fetch the property value.

Similarly, I have read through the ideas here: [Get name of property as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820660/get-name-of-property-as-a-string)

Is there any way of populating the property name from the `GetChildField` function at compile time? Or encoding it into the model somehow?

Comment: If compiling the expression is too slow, have you tried caching the result of that compilation? It wouldn't make the first call any faster, but subsequent calls could benefit. Also, since you seem to accept only expressions of the form `x => x.Property`, have you tried getting the property through reflection instead of compiling the expression?

Comment: Is it possible to cache the result of the compilation? I call the method that compiles the expression with many different expressions across the codebase so it would need to be cached on a per call basis. Your second point is correct though. I have managed to improve the performance by removing the compilation and getting the property through reflection, however it's still not ideal as the property name is still calculated at runtime (I believe.. unless the compiler does something funky).

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have the same problem.

Comment: No I didn't. I did manage to optimise the code to avoid the expensive code path but ultimately it was still using reflection and was the primary cause of slowdown. However, the service was deemed fast enough so further optimisation wasn't needed. Unfortunately I've changed jobs and left the code behind in my previous company but my comment above summarises the approach i believe. (I can't remember further details, sorry)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by following:

```
Item model=new Item();    
var propertyInfo = model.GetType();    
var value=propertyInfo.GetProperty("IrrA").GetValue(model, null).ToString();
```

Comment: Didn't the OP asked for no reflection solution?

Comment: @kuskmen Actually no, OP did not ask for a no reflection solution. OP only stated that compiling an expression was too slow. This might be faster than compiling the expression (or not - I did not test).

Comment: I asked for a solution that calculated the property name at compile time, not run time. However, this solution is faster than compiling the expression.

Answer (score -1):

According to the Roslyn documentation found [here](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/570551) the `nameof` operator is **evaluated at compile-time** per the first line under the "Semantics" section that reads

> The nameof expression is a constant. In all cases, nameof(...) is evaluated at compile-time to produce a string. Its argument is not evaluated at runtime, and is considered unreachable code (however it does not emit an "unreachable code" warning).