# How to pass lambda Expression from one function to other function as parameter?

Tags: c#

I have following class (some part is copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35095504/5779732)):

```
class TestExpression
{
    public string GetValue(Expression<Func<object>> field)
    {
        string str = GetColumnName(field);
        //Do something with 'str'
        return str;//Return modified 'str'
    }

    public string GetColumnName<TType>(Expression<Func<TType>> field)
    {
        var me = field.Body as MemberExpression;
        if(me == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("You must pass a lambda of the form: '() => Class.Property' or '() => object.Property'");
        }
        return me.Member.Name;
    }
}

public sealed class MyClass
{
    public static int StaticProperty { get; set; }
    public int InstanceProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Following is the way I use above class:

```
TestExpression te = new TestExpression();
string name;
name = te.GetColumnName(() => MyClass.StaticProperty);//Works correctly
name = te.GetColumnName(() => new MyClass().InstanceProperty);//Works correctly

name = te.GetValue(() => MyClass.StaticProperty);//Fail
name = te.GetValue(() => new MyClass().InstanceProperty);//Fail
```

So, if I call the `GetColumnName()` function directly, it works all great. But, I need to use this logic at multiple locations, that is why I put it in separate function and call from other functions (like `GetValue()`). In that case, it does not work. In that case, `field.Body as MemberExpression` evaluates to `null`.

I do not want to expose `GetColumnName()` as `public`; it will be `private` function.

How to pass lambda from one function to other function as parameter?

Comment: Just turning the `GetValue()` method generic, makes it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your C# code actually includes a type-cast, which you don't see because in the C#, but does happen on the Expression since the expected type is `Expression<Func<object>>` (note the `object`!).

```
() => MyClass.StaticProperty
```

is actually:

```
() => (object)MyClass.StaticProperty
```

The `(object)` part converts to `Convert(MyClass.StaticProperty)`. The suddenly this isn't a `MemberExpression` any more, it is a `UnaryExpression`.

You can prevent all this by making the method generic, thus avoiding the required cast to `object`:

```
public string GetValue<TType>(Expression<Func<TType>> field)
```

Comment: Worth noting that typecast happens because `StaticProperty` is value-type (int). If it were reference type, such as string - there would be no typecast.

Comment: Indeed, that is true @Evk

Answer (score 1):

Change the signature of the GetValue method to:

```
public string GetValue<T>(Expression<Func<T>> field)
```

Otherwise you are operating on the object where your properties are not visible.