# Get string property name from expression

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, lambda

I'm trying to write a strongly typed helper
which would be something like this:

```
Html.Lookup(x => x.FooId);
```

for now I have this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString Lookup<T,TReturn>(this HtmlHelper<T> html, Func<T, TReturn> expression)
{
     // get string "FooId" here
}
```

Anybody knows how to get this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the property, as a string, from an Expression<Func<TModel,TProperty>>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789504/get-the-property-as-a-string-from-an-expressionfunctmodel-tproperty)

Comment: Why are you reinventing `ViewData.ModelMetadata`?

Comment: @Craig Stuntz I don't really get what you mean, I just want to create a strongly typed helper

Comment: You're creating a helper for functionality which already exists. It's not clear, from your question, what problem you're trying to solve by doing so.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get method name and type using lambda expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273941/get-method-name-and-type-using-lambda-expression)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
public static class ExpressionsExtractor
{
    public static string Lookup<T, TProp>(this HtmlHelper<T> html, Expression<Func<T, TProp>> expression)
    {
        var memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;

        if (memberExpression == null)
            return null;

        return memberExpression.Member.Name;
    }
}
```

You would then call it with:

```
var propName = Html.Lookup(x => x.FooId);
```

Comment: i think this should work, but it look like I've didn't declared my expression correctly or something cuz I can't use it the I wanted

Comment: `return memberExpression == null ? null : memberExpression.Member.Name;`

Comment: This won't work with value types. With value type expression will be something along the '{x => Convert(x.Property)}'. You'll need to cast it to UnaryExpression and then cast its operand to MemberExpression.

Comment: @slawek thanks! been struggling with this for an hour

Answer (score 14):

Yet another code.

```
public MvcHtmlString Lookup<T, TReturn>(this HtmlHelper<T> html, Expression<Func<T, TReturn>> expression)
{
  return MvcHtmlString.Create(ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression));
}
```

Use ExpressionHelper class.
Func is delegate, Expression is generate ExpressionTree at compile time.
Expression.Compile() return delegate, but Func don't get ExpressionTree at runtime.

Comment: This also return the "Class.PropertName" contrary to answer accepted above.

Answer (score 8):

Currently using this class when I need this functionality outside of web project where `System.Web.Mvc` reference shouldn't exist:

```
namespace Interreg.Domain{
  using System;
  using System.Linq.Expressions;
  public class PropertyName{
    public static string For<T>(
      Expression<Func<T,object>> expression){
      var body=expression.Body;
      return GetMemberName(body);
    }
    public static string For(
      Expression<Func<object>> expression){
      var body=expression.Body;
      return GetMemberName(body);
    }
    public static string GetMemberName(
      Expression expression){
      if(expression is MemberExpression){
        var memberExpression=(MemberExpression)expression;
        if(memberExpression.Expression.NodeType==
           ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
          return GetMemberName(memberExpression.Expression)+"."+memberExpression.Member.Name;
        return memberExpression.Member.Name;
      }
      if(expression is UnaryExpression){
        var unaryExpression=(UnaryExpression)expression;
        if(unaryExpression.NodeType!=ExpressionType.Convert)
          throw new Exception(string.Format("Cannot interpret member from {0}",expression));
        return GetMemberName(unaryExpression.Operand);
      }
      throw new Exception(string.Format("Could not determine member from {0}",expression));
    }
  }
}
```

Good thing about this one is - it does not lose dots when going deeper than just one level.

Answer (score 0):

a bit late but I am posting a simple solution that's working for me in .Net 4. It has handling for value types on line 4

```
public PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfo<TSource>(Expression<Func<TSource, object>> propertyLambda) {
        var member = propertyLambda.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (member == null) {// value types return Convert(x.property) which can't be cast to MemberExpression
            var expression = propertyLambda.Body as UnaryExpression;
            member = expression.Operand as MemberExpression;
        }
        return member.Member as PropertyInfo;
    }
```