# Method returns different string second call - Arguments are the same

Tags: c#, .net, string, reflection, stringbuilder

I am currently having trouble understanding why the output of the method below is different the second time it is called.

```
/// <summary>
    /// Method which given an object will produce the sql string part.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Object type</typeparam>
    /// <param name="modelObject">The object to assess</param>
    /// <param name="param">true if appending @ (aka parameter)</param>
    /// <returns>the string part of the sql.</returns>
    public static string GetInsertParamString<T>(T modelObject, bool param = false)
    {
        //simple stringbuilder to hold the string we will return
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        //loop through each of the proporties of the object
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in modelObject.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            //if the value of this object is not null - then add to the string
            if (modelObject.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name)?.GetValue(modelObject, null) != null)
            {
                //if param == true then add the @ before.
                str.Append(param ? "@" + prop.Name : prop.Name).Append(",");
            }
        }
        //return the string.
        return str.ToString().Remove(str.Length - 1, 1);
    }
```

I am calling the method using the following line of C# code:

```
private static string InsertCrmSql<T>(T obj, string table) => @"INSERT INTO " + table + @" (" + SqlHelper.GetInsertParamString(obj) + @") VALUES (" + SqlHelper.GetInsertParamString(obj) + @")";
```

This demonstrates that the method is being called twice with the exact same parameter. **NB: For debugging , I have removed the true value from the second call to ensure that this was not causing the problem.**

When running In debug after the first call to the method the following is returned:

[image: Result from first call]
The final **initial** call string builder value clearer:

> ```
> {wc_id,wc_status,wc_custref,wc_cuname,wc_transid,wc_transtype,wc_reqdate,wc_store,wc_salesman,wc_analysis1,wc_analysis2,wc_analysis3,wc_analysis4,wc_analysis5,wc_analysis6,wc_analysis7,wc_analysis8,wc_analysis9,}
> ```

However on the second call the following is found :

[image: Result from second call]
The final **second** call string builder value:

> {wc_analysis1,wc_analysis2,wc_analysis3,wc_analysis4,wc_analysis5,wc_analysis6,wc_analysis7,wc_analysis8,wc_analysis9,wc_id,wc_status,wc_custref,wc_cuname,wc_transid,wc_transtype,wc_reqdate,wc_store,wc_salesman,}

Is anyone able to provide and insight or an explanation as to why this is happening?

I should also add its the same everytime the program is ran - the first result and then the second result

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's most likely because, from [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x(v=vs.110).aspx) of `Type.GetProperties()`:

> The GetProperties method does not return properties in a particular
>   order, such as alphabetical or declaration order. **Your code must not**
>   **depend on the order in which properties are returned**, because that
>   order varies.

As you might have noticed - names in both of your strings are the same, just order is different.

So you need to enumerate properties in a consistent order, such as:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo prop in modelObject.GetType().GetProperties().OrderBy(c => c.Name))
```

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11403362/152997), metadata is available to obtain the original declaration order.