# VB.NET function get property name as string

Tags: .net, vb.net, function, properties, parameters

I'm trying to create a function that when a property is passed to it as a parameter, it returns the name used to define the property as a string. For example,

```
Shared Function PropertyToStr(Propert As Object)
     'Code to get property name and return it as a string goes here  
End Function
```

Providing that `First_Name` is a the name of a property, defined like:

```
Property First_Name as String
```

The function should work like:

```
Dim str as String = PropertyToStr(First_Name) ' Resulting in str = "First_Name"
```

Note I ONLY want in this function to return the property name "First_Name", and not "MyClass.First_Name" for example.

I have found other examples of similar code to my function I require written in c# yet I have not been able to replicate their use of the MemberExpression in VB.Net

[Getting sub property names strongly typed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17882930/getting-sub-property-names-strongly-typed)

[Get name of property as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820660/get-name-of-property-as-a-string)

[Retrieving Property name from lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671968/retrieving-property-name-from-lambda-expression)

Comment: I two would like to know the answer to this, great question @Jason

Answer (score 13):

Edit:  In Visual Studio 2015 ([VB 14 or later](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/nameof)) you can use the `NameOf` operator to accomplish this:

```
Property First_Name As String

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    MessageBox.Show(NameOf(First_Name))
End Sub
```

Original answer for older versions of .net:

Running those other answers through some code converters and cleaning it up yields the following, which seems to work just fine.

```
Private Shared Function GetMemberInfo(method As Expression) As MemberExpression
    Dim lambda As LambdaExpression = TryCast(method, LambdaExpression)
    If lambda Is Nothing Then
        Throw New ArgumentNullException("method")
    End If

    Dim memberExpr As MemberExpression = Nothing

    If lambda.Body.NodeType = ExpressionType.Convert Then
        memberExpr = TryCast(DirectCast(lambda.Body, UnaryExpression).Operand, MemberExpression)
    ElseIf lambda.Body.NodeType = ExpressionType.MemberAccess Then
        memberExpr = TryCast(lambda.Body, MemberExpression)
    End If

    If memberExpr Is Nothing Then
        Throw New ArgumentException("method")
    End If

    Return memberExpr
End Function

Public Shared Function GetPropertyName(Of T)(prop As Expression(Of Func(Of T))) As String
    Dim expression = GetMemberInfo(prop)
    Return expression.Member.Name
End Function

Property First_Name As String
Property LastName As String
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    MessageBox.Show(GetPropertyName(Function() First_Name))
    MessageBox.Show(GetPropertyName(Function() LastName))
End Sub
```