# How to get the full name of the property from a lambda

Tags: c#, lambda

I use the following method to create a SelectListItem object from any other object:

```
public static SelectListItem ToSelectListItem<T, TResult, TResult2>(T obj, Expression<Func<T, TResult>> value, Expression<Func<T, TResult2>> text)
{
    string strValue = String.Empty;
    string strText = String.Empty;

    if (value != null)
          strValue = (value.Body as MemberExpression).Member.Name;

    if (text != null)
          strText = (text.Body as MemberExpression).Member.Name;
         ...
 }
```

I use this method like this:

```
SelectListItem item = ToSelectListItem(obj, x => x.ID, x => x.Name);
```

And it works fine. However, when I specify a property from an associated object all I get is the name of the property

```
SelectListItem item = ToSelectListItem(obj, x => x.ID, x => x.Profile.Name);
```

The property name I'm able to get from 'x => x.Profile.Name' is only 'Name' and what I really wanted to get was 'Profile.Name'.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#: Getting Names of properties in a chain from lambda expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667408/c-getting-names-of-properties-in-a-chain-from-lambda-expression)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you can use

```
expression.Compile().Invoke(obj)
```

if you want to use `Expression<>`

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier to use Func instead of Expression<>

To manipulate the property all I have to do is invoke it:

```
expression.Invoke(obj);
```