# Getting Names of properties in a chain from NewExpression members

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda, linq-expressions

Suppose this expression:

```
Expression<Func<DateTime, dynamic>> exp = dt => new { dt.Second, dt.Hour, dt.Date.Day };
```

I need to obtain the following: `"Second", "Hour", "Date.Day"`

The best I've been able to accomplish is the following:

```
var body = exp.Body as NewExpression;
foreach(var member in body.Members)
    member.Name().Dump();
```

But I only get: `"Second", "Hour", "Day"`

---

This is somewhat similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667408/c-getting-names-of-properties-in-a-chain-from-lambda-expression) but I'm dealing with a NewExpression here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can try on `Arguments` instead of `Members`.

```
var body = exp.Body as NewExpression;
foreach (var member in body.Arguments)
{
    Console.WriteLine(member);
}
```

Output is:

```
dt.Second
dt.Hour
dt.Date.Day
```