# Execute/Invoke ConditionalExpression to decided if to use true- or false part

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees, invoke

I want to have the possibility to build the propertyname-chain from a given expression. I've taken the source for the conversation from here ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1667533/615288)).

This works pretty well when used as described there.

My problem now is when I'm passing an conditional expression, e.g.

> Foo((MyClass c) => createChain ? c.SomeProperty : null);

whereas `createChain` is a `bool` and inside the `Foo` the first check is for an `expr != null` to go further.

However, `expr.Body.NodeType` is now `ExpressionType.Conditional` and I don't find the right way to execute/invoke the expression so I know which part (true or false) of the expression I should set for `me`.

I've added `case ExpressionType.Conditional:` and casted `var ce = expr as ConditionalExpression`. How can I get the correct expression to be used for `me` from `ce` as one is the `c.SomeProperty` whereas the other one would be `null` depending on the value of `createChain`.

```
case ExpressionType.Conditional:
    var ce = expr.Body as ConditionalExpression;
    me = (MemberExpression) (ce != null && /*ce.Invoke()*/ ? ce.IfTrue : ce.IfFalse); // here i need to know if to use true or false part of expr
    break;
```

Comment: I don't find this clear enough...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
            case ExpressionType.Conditional:
                var ce = expr.Body as ConditionalExpression;
                var cond = (MemberExpression)ce.Test;
                me = (MemberExpression) (ce != null && (bool)(Expression.Lambda(cond).Compile().DynamicInvoke()) ? ce.IfTrue : ce.IfFalse); 
                break;
```

Comment: This throws `InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.FieldExpression' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression'.`

Comment: Updated. Although you may still have a problem if your conditional expression evaluates to null as obviously that won't cast to a MemberExpression

Comment: Thanks. Using safe casting and checking against `null` seems to do the trick for my case

Comment: Line 3 throws `Unable to cast object of type System.Linq.Expressions.LogicalBinaryExpression to type System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression`.