# C# How to get nameof a sentence as String

Tags: c#, reflection

I need to identify the list of properties that are being called as String.
For example:

```
Person person = new Person();
// Arm, Hand and Finger are public properties
Foo(person.Arm.Hand.Finger);
```

I need *person.Arm.Hand.Finger* as a String, if I write **nameof** I only get *Finger* but I need the whole invocation.
Of course I can use Foo("person.Arm.Hand.Finger") but I don't want to do that.

**Note:** I need this to perform a query using that specific String. I tried with reflection but I cant get caller of the property.

Comment: you could do it with an expression tree.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667408/c-getting-names-of-properties-in-a-chain-from-lambda-expression

Comment: @DanielA.White even for the `person` part?

Comment: @RenéVogt it should.

Comment: @DanielA.White right, test the first answer, it does exactly that

Comment: WOW Thanks it worked, sorry for the duplicated question